# Filter Categories in Tagged Items Menu Item Type

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item, tags

I'm making a menu to retrieve all articles that have certain tags and are from a certain category using **"Tagged Items"** menu item type,
I managed to get all articles that have certain tags, however, **"Tagged Items"** is bringing articles from all categories,
I tried to search in the menu item options for an option that would let me select the categories, but to no avail,

My question is, is there a way to retrieve articles from just one category of articles using **"Tagged Items"**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating a Tagged Items menu item type, you can create either a Category Blog or Category List menu item (part of the Articles group of menu item types). Either of these menu item types will allow you to choose an article category and also an optional list of tags.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I tried using the Category Blog menu type already, but I wanted to use the "Tagged Items" menu type since it already has a filter to search for articles. Do you know if there is a way to include the same filter in the Category Blog menu?

Comment: The Category List menu item type offers a Filter Field option, which will show a filter field selector at the top of the list. The filter allows readers to search for articles by title, author, hits, tags or month: you choose which attribute to search.

Category Blog menu item doesn't offer a filter field, but you can get that effect with a Smart Search module, e.g. in a sidebar on the blog page. That lets users run full text searches for articles. Limit the module's search scope to a category by creating a Search Filter in the Smart Search component, then use it in the Smart Search module.